# Strange error while attempting to use Zip task from .net 4.0 version of MSBuild.ExtensionPack

Tags: .net-4.0, msbuild, zip

We've been getting inconsistent results from the Zip task in Tigris MSBuild task library, so we're trying to use the Zip task in the MSBuild.ExtensionPack for .NET 4.0.  But when we execute this new Zip task, we get the following error from the MSBuild executable:

> C:\development\build\PrepareLastKnownGood.csproj(40,3): error : Typ
>   eInitializationException: The type initializer for 'java.lang.System' threw an
>   exception.\r
>   C:\development\build\PrepareLastKnownGood.csproj(40,3): error : Unsat
>   isfiedLinkError: Unable to load DLL 'vjsnativ': The specified module could not
>   be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)\r

Has anyone else encountered this error in their use of the Zip task from MSBuild.ExtensionPack?  If so, how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zip task from *MSBuild.ExtensionPack.JSharp.dll*  is implemented in J#. And has dependency to the **vjslib.dll**.
You need to install [Microsoft Visual J# Version 2.0 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=f72c74b3-ed0e-4af8-ae63-2f0e42501be1&displaylang=en).